why am i getting 404 error after successful payment by stripe only after deploying
I built an food-e-commerce as part of personal project. Personally I had experience with web development but never with Stripe so I had to learn everything from scratch in many points of this project.

vercel page after payment
//backend controllers 
exports.verifyOrder = async (req, res) => {
    const {orderId,success}=req.body;
    try {
        if(success=="true"){
            await orderModel.findByIdAndUpdate(orderId, { payment : true });
            res.status(200).json({
                success: true,
                message: "Paid"
            });
        }
        else{
            await orderModel.findByIdAndDelete(orderId);
            res.status(200).json({
                success: false,
                message: "Payment failed"
            });
        }

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({
            success: false,
            message: error.message
        });
    }
}
 

frontend
url=backend url

const Verify = () => {

    const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
    const success = searchParams.get('success')
    const orderId = searchParams.get('order_id')
    console.log(success,orderId);
    const {url}=useContext(StoreContext)
    const navigate=useNavigate();
    const verifyPayment = async () => {
        const response = await axios.post(url+"/api/order/verify",{success:success,orderId});
        console.log(response);
        console.log(response.data.success);
        if(response.data.success){
            navigate("/myorders")
        }
        else{
            navigate("/")
        }
    }
    useEffect(()=>{
        verifyPayment()
    },[])
  return (
    <div className='verify'>
        <div className='spinner'>

        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Verify

this is my github link https://github.com/Vrchsav/Food-Ecommerce-
this is my proj link https://food-ecommerce-pi.vercel.app/
this is my env file
port no  this port is correct i have checked
after successful payment ir will direct be navigated to cart components

Which specific endpoint throw 404? Is it thrown from Stripe or your internal server?

when u complete ur payment after that  https://food-ecommerce-pi.vercel.app/ u can also try                                                                                                                        Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
